# Merging videos with non-standard dimensions

Tags: linux, video-editing

Is there a good application in linux for attaching mkv videos. *mkvmerge* corrupts the videos with unusable output. *Openshot* has predefined output size while I have videos with non-standard dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on Linux/[Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)/Mac
- CLI
- Allows to [concatenate MKV](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files):

> With a text file called mergelist.txt (or whatever you want to call it), i.e.:
>
> ```
> file './file1.mkv'
> file './file2.mkv'
> file './file3.mkv'
> ```
>
> you can use that as the input:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -f concat -i mergelist.txt -c copy merged.mkv
> ```

Comment: unfortunaley ffmpeg is not available in Ubuntu Trusty. I had to compile it. it works now.